# Django Field 'id' expected a number but got 'coding'

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, blogs

I am getting errors while trying to display all the posts related to one category.
**Error Message: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'coding'**

View Code:

```
def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Item.objects.filter(item_category=cats)
    return render(request, 'waqart/categories.html', {'cats':cats, 'category_posts':category_posts })
```

URL:

path('category/str:cats/', CategoryView, name='category'),

Template File:

```
{%extends 'waqart/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{cats}}</h1> 
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
{% for item in category_posts %}

  <h2 class="text-gray-900 text-xl title-font font-medium"{{item.title|truncatechars:40}}</h2>

{% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Model:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        

        return self.name



class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description= RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    main_image= models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to='images/')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    item_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)
    item_category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, default='Coding', on_delete=SET_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Please share your `Category` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Model fields added. Thanks and appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you filter on the `ForeignKey`, then Django will filter on the *primary* key of the target object, and that is normally an `AutoField`, unless you referred to another (unique) column, or defined another primary key as field.

You likely want to filter on the *slug* of the category:

```
def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Item.objects.filter(item_category__slug=cats)
    return render(
        request,
        'waqart/categories.html',
        {'cats':cats, 'category_posts':category_posts }
    )
```

If you need to fetch the category as well, we can do this in two queries with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=cats)
    category_posts = Item.objects.filter(item_category=category)
    return render(
        request,
        'waqart/categories.html',
        {'category': category, 'category_posts':category_posts }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. It works :) Really appreciated